# Running projects from QtCreator after cmake install

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

have some real trouble with QtCreator on ubuntu 18 and was wondering if anyone could give me any help. This morning I installed cmake for another project I was working on, now when I try to run a project in qtcreator it is trying to deploy it via FTP, even though it is a Qt c++ project. I dont know if this is anything to do with cmake, but this worked last night before I installed it. My question is, can anybody explain to me how to run a project from QtCreator, on the local system( Terminal or otherwise, doesnt matter ) without any deployment issues. Im sorry if this is a stupid question, but I am extremely grateful for any hep

Answer (score 0):

In a console, you can just cd into the project directory (where the .pro file resides) and execute "qmake" and then "make". That should compile your executable which you can then run using "./[executable filename]" or "/[path]/[executable filename]". Also, on the console you might see where this FTP transfer comes from. Also, in QtCreator you can set the build system and change that from cmake to something else to see if its a cmake problem.

Comment: This will work if one is unable to create a build to point QtCreator to. See my below answer

Answer (score 0):

So, not sure how this issue came up, but I have found a workaround after much trial and error. Open a project, In the left tab click Projects and under build and run select Run. In this menu deploy steps have already been added when i create a project, so these need to be deleted. Now in the Run section on the same screen Click add -> Custom executable and select the file that has already been built for the project in question. In my case this solves the above problem, but does not explain why QtCreator is trying to deploy C++ projects via FTP. If anyone out there is struggling with this issue feel free to post a question here and I will assist as much as possible!